# Circlepage indicator to imageview using sliding

Tags: android

I want to add a circle indicator to images when images change from one to another.  The circle indicator has to change at the same time.

Comment: are you using the VIewPager?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ViewPager` and `Fragment` to do this. The activity layout should contains a `ViewPager` inside. and the `Fragment` layout needs nothing but an `ImageView`.

In Java code, the fragment needs an adapter, which should be something like this:

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private ArrayList<String> imageList;
        private int imagePosition;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, ArrayList<String> imageList, int imagePosition) {
            super(fragmentManager);

            this.imageList = imageList;
            this.imagePosition = imagePosition;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {
            return new GalleryFragment(imageList.get(index));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imageList.size();
        }

    }
```

`imageList` is used to hold the URLs of pictures you want to display. You can just replace it by `ArrayList<Integer> imageList` if the pictures you want to show is in the drawable folder.

For the indicator part, TextView with text "●" would be fine.It may looks a little strange, but it's quite neat and easy. You can change the size and the color of the indicators as you wish.

Then what's left is just to put the `Fragment` into `ViewPager`

```
gallery_pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(GalleryActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager(),
                curImageList, imagePosition));
        gallery_pager.setCurrentItem(imagePosition);
        gallery_pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int index) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i = 0; i < curImageList.size(); i++) {
                    PagerIndicator[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    PagerIndicator[i].setTextColor(0xff666666);

                    if (i == index) {
                        PagerIndicator[i].setTextColor(0xffffffff);
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

In the method `onPageSelected` you can controll how the dots would be like when a picture is slided to.

---

**Edited**

Most parts of the codes had been added above, what you may need is the code for the Fragment:

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment{

    private Context context;
    private String imageUrl;

    public GalleryFragment(String imageUrl)
    {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        context = GalleryFragment.this.getActivity();

        ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        image.setLayoutParams(params);
        image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

        //TODO use the imageUrl to load and display the image;

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.addView(image);

        return layout;
    }


}
```

and the XML of the activity should be like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#222222" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/gallery_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"

                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dot1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="●"
                    android:textColor="#15EDE2"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <!--add as many dots here as you need. If the size of the imageList changes, just keep the same amount of dots VISIBLE and others GONE-->
            </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: could you please send me full code..as i am new to android.@Jack Xu

Comment: as i am using this below XML file, Please share java code for this , images arein drawable folder...

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card1x1ParentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/card1x1ImageView"
        android:src="@drawable/image"/>
    <utils.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_pager"
        android:padding="10dip" />

Comment: @Mujeeb Rahman Edited the answer and add some code above. Hopes it may help.